# sub-substrings present x times in at least one substring of a string in python

Tags: python, string, substring, frequency, slice

I am trying to find the sub-substring(s) with certain frequency in a list a substrings (i.e.windows) of a larger string in python. It is, the goal is to find what sub-substrings (of a fixed length) are present (if any, in certain required frequency) in at least one of the substrings:

```
strand='JJJKJKHHGHJKKLHHGJJJHHGJJJ'
#now, I break the string by windows (substrings) and define the patterns to look (sub-substrings) :

A=20 #(fixed lenght of each window (substring) moving along the string in a one-by-one way)
B=3 #(fixed length of the pattern (sub-substring))
C=3 #(frequency of pattern (sub-substring))
pattcount = {}
for i in range(0, len(strand)-A+1):
  win=strand[i:i+A]
  for n in range(0, len(win)-B+1):
   patt=win[n:n+B]
   pattcount[patt] = pattcount[patt] + 1 if pattcount.has_key(patt) else 1

pattgroup = []
for p,f in pattcount.iteritems():
   if f != C:
     pattgroup = pattgroup
   elif f == C:
     pattgroup += [p]

print (" ".join(pattgroup))
```

therefore, I obtain as a result:
JKJ
When the answer should be only:
HHG (it is contained C=3 times in a window of length 20)
And no JKJ or JJJ (the latter is contained C=3 times but in the entire string, not in a window of lenght 20)

What am I doing wrong? How can I find just the patterns present in the needed frequency but in at least one window? (without adding any match of the pattern from other windows to the final count)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When i print pattcount before checking the freq. i get 'HHG': 18.

Comment: yes, the script is surely counting the 3 times HHG appears but considering the sum in the 6 subtrings (=18), but in this case it should report just HHG by being present 3 times in at least a substring of lenght 20 (along the mainstring)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the program runs through the windows (7 in this case) and counts the frequency of every pattern without resetting. So in the end, it finds that HHG is encountered 18 times (like badc0re says). You ask that it finds 3 repetitions so JKJ is provided because it is found only 3 times throughout all the windows.

So basically, you have to reset that pattcount variable every time you start a new window. You can store the pattcount of each window in another variable such as pattcounttotal. I've made a rough example:

```
strand='JJJKJKHHGHJKKLHHGJJJHHGJJJ'
#now, I break the string by windows (substrings) and define the patterns to look (sub-substrings) :

A=20 #(fixed lenght of each window (substring) moving along the string in a one-by-one way)
B=3 #(fixed length of the pattern (sub-substring))
C=3 #(frequency of pattern (sub-substring))

pattcounttotal = {} #So in this var everything will be stored   

for i in range(0, len(strand)-A+1):
    pattcount = {}  #This one is moved inside the for loop so it is emptied with every window
    win=strand[i:i+A]
    for n in range(0, len(win)-B+1):
        patt=win[n:n+B]

        #I've partly rewritten your code to make it more readable (for me)
        if pattcount.has_key(patt):
            pattcount[patt] = pattcount[patt] + 1
        else:
            pattcount[patt] = 1

    pattcounttotal[i] = pattcount  #This pattcount is stored into the total one
```

Now you have to go through pattcounttotal (instead of pattcount) to find a pattern which is repeated three times over only one window.

The output, I receive when I "print" the pattcounttotal var, is given below:

```
{0: {'HGH': 1, 'KJK': 1, 'KLH': 1, 'HJK': 1, 'LHH': 1, 'KHH': 1, 'KKL': 1, 'GJJ': 1, 'HGJ': 1, 'JJK': 1, 'JJJ': 2, 'JKJ': 1, 'JKK': 1, 'JKH': 1, 'HHG': 2, 'GHJ': 1}, 
1: {'JJH': 1, 'HGH': 1, 'KJK': 1, 'JKK': 1, 'KLH': 1, 'LHH': 1, 'KHH': 1, 'KKL': 1, 'GJJ': 1, 'HGJ': 1, 'JJK': 1, 'HJK': 1, 'JKJ': 1, 'JKH': 1, 'HHG': 2, 'GHJ': 1, 'JJJ': 1}, 
2: {'JHH': 1, 'HGH': 1, 'KJK': 1, 'JJH': 1, 'KLH': 1, 'LHH': 1, 'KHH': 1, 'KKL': 1, 'GJJ': 1, 'HGJ': 1, 'JKH': 1, 'HJK': 1, 'JKJ': 1, 'JKK': 1, 'HHG': 2, 'GHJ': 1, 'JJJ': 1}, 
3: {'JHH': 1, 'KJK': 1, 'JJH': 1, 'KLH': 1, 'LHH': 1, 'KHH': 1, 'KKL': 1, 'GJJ': 1, 'HGJ': 1, 'JKH': 1, 'HJK': 1, 'HGH': 1, 'JKK': 1, 'HHG': 3, 'GHJ': 1, 'JJJ': 1}, 
4: {'JHH': 1, 'JJH': 1, 'KLH': 1, 'LHH': 1, 'KHH': 1, 'KKL': 1, 'GJJ': 1, 'HGJ': 2, 'HHG': 3, 'GHJ': 1, 'HGH': 1, 'JKK': 1, 'JKH': 1, 'HJK': 1, 'JJJ': 1}, 
5: {'JHH': 1, 'JJH': 1, 'KLH': 1, 'LHH': 1, 'KHH': 1, 'KKL': 1, 'GJJ': 2, 'HHG': 3, 'GHJ': 1, 'HGH': 1, 'JKK': 1, 'HGJ': 2, 'HJK': 1, 'JJJ': 1}, 
6: {'JHH': 1, 'JJH': 1, 'KLH': 1, 'LHH': 1, 'KKL': 1, 'GJJ': 2, 'HHG': 3, 'GHJ': 1, 'HGH': 1, 'JKK': 1, 'HGJ': 2, 'HJK': 1, 'JJJ': 2}}
```

So basically each window is numbered from 0-6 and the frequencies of each pattern are presented. So if I glance over it quickly, I see that in windows 3-5 the HHG pattern is encountered 3 times.

*(If you want an "automated" output than you still have to write a piece of code that cycles through each window (so through the upper level of the dictionary) and keeps track of the patterns that are encountered three times.) updated*

I thought it was a fun problem so I made that "automated" output too. It was very similar to what you already had. Here is the code I used (hopefully it's not a spoiler :) )

```
pattgroup = []
for i in pattcounttotal.iteritems(): #It first retrieves the upper levels of pattcounttotal
    for p,f in i[1].iteritems(): #i[0] is the window's number and i[1] is the dictionary that contains the frequencies
        if f != C:
            pattgroup = pattgroup
        elif f == C:
            if not(p in pattgroup):  #This makes sure if HHG is not already in pattgroup.
                pattgroup += [p]        

print (" ".join(pattgroup))
```

If I put these two codes together and run the program, I get HHG back.

Comment: I've edited a couple times to rephrase some of my answer and to provide the "automated" output.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with other strands and I obtained the expected result.

Comment: You're welcome. You can check my answer as correct than other people know that the question is answered and the topic is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify to

```
from collections import defaultdict

strand='JJJKJKHHGHJKKLHHGJJJHHGJJJ'
print strand
A=20
B=3
C=3

D = A-B+1
pattcount = defaultdict(int)
res = set()

for i in xrange(len(strand)-A+1):
    pattcount.clear()
    win=strand[i:i+A]
    for n in xrange(D):
        pattcount[win[n:n+B]] += 1
    res.update(k for k,v in pattcount.iteritems() if v==3)
    print 'i==%d   res==%s' % (i,res)

print (" ".join(res))
```

#### Edit

We can even avoid to use **win**:

```
from collections import defaultdict

strand='JJJKJKHHGHJKKLHHGJJJHHGJJJ'
print strand

A=20
B=3
C=3

D = A-B+1
pattcount = defaultdict(int)
res = set()

for i in xrange(len(strand)-A+1):
    pattcount.clear()
    for n in xrange(i,i+D):
        pattcount[strand[n:n+B]] += 1
    res.update(k for k,v in pattcount.iteritems() if v==3)

print (" ".join(res))
```